# VirtualTreeView Memory Leak with Objects

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, virtualtreeview

I'm using the code provided by [Cosmin Prund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282676/cosmin-prund) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365365/tree-like-datastructure-for-use-with-virtualtreeview/5370981#5370981) because it fits my needs however I often get memory leak and I could not figure out how to free the node which it's `TNode` object that contain `TObjectList` in turn this last can also contain `TNode` that also contain `TObjectList` and so on... it's some kind of recursion I though,

As I know to free the node in `VirtualTreeView` according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282676/cosmin-prund) the node need to be validated and to be finalised within the `OnFreeNode` event this code return Invalid pointer operation and of course memory leak report:

```
procedure TfrmFichePermission.VSTFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  AObject:TObject;
  ANode: TNode;
begin
  AObject := TObject(VST.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  ANode := TNode(AObject);
  ANode.Free;
end;
```

this is a full example to reproduce the memory leak

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, VirtualTrees, System.Generics.Collections,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TNode = class;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    VST: TVirtualStringTree;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure VSTGetNodeDataSize(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      var NodeDataSize: Integer);
    procedure VSTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
      Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure AddNodestoTree(ParentNode: PVirtualNode; Node: TNode);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TNode = class
  public
    Name: string;
    VTNode: PVirtualNode;
    Sub: TObjectList<TNode>;
    constructor Create(aName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TNode.Create(aName:string);
begin
  Name := aName;
  Sub := TObjectList<TNode>.Create;
end;

destructor TNode.Destroy;
begin
  Sub.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddNodestoTree(ParentNode: PVirtualNode; Node: TNode);
var SubNode: TNode;
    ThisNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  ThisNode := VST.AddChild(ParentNode, Node); // This call adds a new TVirtualNode to the VT, and saves "Node" as the payload

  Node.VTNode := ThisNode; // Save the PVirtualNode for future reference. This is only an example,
                           // the same TNode might be registered multiple times in the same VT,
                           // so it would be associated with multiple PVirtualNode's.

  for SubNode in Node.Sub do
    AddNodestoTree(ThisNode, SubNode);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Root: TNode;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  VST.Clear;
  //
  Root := TNode.Create('Test1');
  Root.Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test2'));
  Root.Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test3'));
  Root.Sub[1].Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test4'));
  Root.Sub[1].Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test5'));
  AddNodesToTree(nil, Root);
  //
  Root := TNode.Create('Test1');
  Root.Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test2'));
  Root.Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test3'));
  Root.Sub[1].Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test4'));
  Root.Sub[1].Sub.Add(TNode.Create('Test5'));
  AddNodesToTree(nil, Root);
  //
end;
procedure TForm1.VSTGetNodeDataSize(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  var NodeDataSize: Integer);
begin
  NodeDataSize := SizeOf(Pointer);
end;

procedure TForm1.VSTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
    AObject:TObject;
    ANode: TNode;
begin
  AObject := TObject(VST.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  ANode := TNode(AObject);
  CellText := ANode.Name;
end;

end.
```

Memory Leak report :

[image]

Comment: `TObjectList` owns the objects by default.

Comment: Why do you cast to TObject and then to TNode? Why not straight to TNode? How do we know what TNode is? What if there's a bug there? Why do you post only a small amount of code. It would be easy to post a short .dpr for a console app that was complete and demonstrated the problem. Had you done so you'd have had an answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @David Heffernan you know i was just about to ask the same question about why casting twise TObject than TNode :) for the sample it was the same code as the post i refer to above + the OnFreeNode Event so i post only the extra code...

Comment: What does the leak report *say* is leaking? In Cosmin's code, the `TObjectList<TNode>` *does* own the `TNode` objects, which is probably why he *doesn't* free them in an `OnFreeNode` event handler. You've presented this problem midway through your attempt to solve it. Please back up and show us the leak report, *not* your attempted solution, which merely introduced *more* problems.

Comment: Your real issue is not memory leak, but Invalid pointer operation. Solve this and your memory leaks will most likely be solved too.

Comment: does stackoverflow Notifying you when i edit my post or i need to comment to notfiy you?

Comment: We get no notifications for question edits

Comment: I would recommend you using an object inside the record, see  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136951/how-to-add-objects-to-virtualtreeview  
like  
TYourNodeRecord = record  
YourObject: TYourObject;  
end;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmin's code does not intend for the tree view nodes to own the `TNode` objects. I think in his post you were meant to hold on to the `Root` object and destroy it after the tree is destroyed.

In Cosmin's code the `TNode` objects are owned by the object list that contains them. Right the way up to the root node which is owned by whatever created it. You could do that too. You'd have to remember the root object, and stop destroying the `TNode` objects when tree view nodes were destroyed.

If you want to have the tree view own the `TNode` objects then you can do that. But you need to be clear about the ownership. You can't have the tree view **and** the object lists owning the objects, as you currently do. If the tree view is going to be the owner then you need to set `OwnsObjects` to `False` in the object list. Or even better switch to `TList<TNode>`.

So, to summarise, your present code gives each `TNode` object two owners. The tree view node and the owning object list. Objects need to have exactly one owner. You need to choose between the two options.